# Is there a way to reset the network manager or its settings?

Tags: networking, network-manager, dns

I'm looking for a way to complete reset the configuration or the service it self. I'm not sure it this will fix my issue, which is very unstable connections on some wifi networks. A have been using the computer for a few months without issues, but since recently I'm only able to get a stable connection it the wifi is the hotstop of my phone. Running 22.04.
Did a few tests on the wifi at home and it behaves very weird (other devices are using the same network perfectly, on both 2.4 and 5ghz). `ping` to github's IP (directly so DNS is skipped) stays silents for like 30 seconds, sends like 7-8 pings then stops again, for 30 seconds or so, and this continued indefinitely.

Comment: I would assume you are asking the wrong question: I would start looking at the driver used for your wireless. Network manager itself has nothing to do with your problem so resetting... sure it is possible but it is the device driver and your connection to your router that are important here.

Comment: @Rinzwind Can you point me to a guide for that? I'm new to ubuntu